# Recursion by determinants: $A_{i+1}=A_i+J_n\det A_i$. When does $A_\infty$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, convergence-divergence, determinant, dynamical-systems

Let $i\in\Bbb N$ and $A_i\in[-1,1]^{n\times n}$ be a matrix such that $$A_{i+1}=A_i+J_n\det A_i$$ where $J_n$ denotes the matrix of ones. What can be said about the initial condition $A_1$ for the convergence of $A_\infty$?

In the $2\times2$ scenario I simulated the convergence proportion using a uniform distribution, with convergence determined by the criterion $\operatorname{tr}(J_n\operatorname{abs}A)<M$ for some large $M$.

```
mat_iter <- function(a){
  x <- array(NA, c(2, 2, 500))
  x[,,1] <- matrix(a, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  for(i in 2:500){
    x[,,i] <- x[,,i-1] + det(x[,,i-1])
  }
  return(x[,,500])
}
plot(replicate(50, length(which(replicate(500, sum(abs(mat_iter(runif(4, -1, 1)))))<10^6))/500),
     ylim = c(0.3, 0.7), ylab = "Convergence Proportion", pch = 16)
```

The plot below shows that on average, there is just under a $50\%$ chance of attaining convergence given any $A_1\in[-1,1]^{2\times2}$ (perhaps there is an analytical expression for this). [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d_i=\det(A_i),\,s_i=d_0+d_1+\cdots+d_i$ and $a=e^\top\operatorname{adj}(A_0)e$. By given condition, we have $A_{i+1}=A_0+s_iJ$ for every $i$. Therefore $\{A_i\}$ converges if and only if $\{s_i\}$ converges.

Since $J=ee^\top$ has rank 1, we obtain
$$
d_i
=\det(A_0+s_{i-1}ee^\top)
=\det(A_0)+s_{i-1}e^\top\operatorname{adj}(A_0)e
=d_0+as_{i-1}
$$
and hence $s_i=s_{i-1}+d_i=d_0+(a+1)s_{i-1}$. In turn, $s_i=\sum_{k=0}^i(a+1)^kd_0$. Consequently, $\{A_k\}$ (or $\{s_k\}$) converges if and only if $d_0=0$ or $|a+1|<1$, i.e. if and only if $A_0$ is singular or the sum of all elements of $\operatorname{adj}(A_0)$ lies inside $(-2,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer:

If any $A_i\in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is singular, you will have reached convergence, as your additive part is always zero. Randomizing a singular matrix has a property of $0$, so let's take a look at the iteration.

You are adding a rank-1 update to $A_i$ in every step.
If you write your matrix $A_i$ as $A_i = U Q_i U^{T}$ with $U$ as an (any) orthonormal base of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $\mathbf{1}$ as (scaled) first column, you can rewrite your iteration as
\begin{align*}
A_{i+1} &= A_i + \mathbf{1}\cdot\mathbf{1}^T \det(A_i)\\
 &= U \cdot Q_i \cdot U^{T} + U \begin{pmatrix} N\det(Q_i)  &\cdots  &0 \\\vdots  & \ddots &0 \\  0 & \cdots & 0\end{pmatrix} \cdot U^T \quad\text{Let's call this matrix } W_i.\\
&=U \cdot( Q_i +W_i) \cdot U^T \\
&= U Q_{i+1} U^T
\end{align*}
So you basically can reduce your iteration to an update of the top-left corner of a matrix.

I have no concrete evidence but making a matrix singular, by just changing the top-left value, is somewhat hard to obtain by chance. I guess your simulation consisted of a lot of periodic fluctuations.